# Why would a 2TB Drive say half it's space is used when it isn't.

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2003

I have a 2TB drive on Windows 2003. I copied 120GB of data onto it. It is now showing only 840GB of free space. It's like it knows it's a 2TB drive, but only 1TB is available to me. Why would this be?

The drive (Disk I) is partitioned to 2TB.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer from the screenshots shown is that he hasn't selected all the files on I: when he brought up the properties.  There are probably some hidden folders/files there or it could be that you don't have permissions to list all the subfolders.  But basically there are 1000GB of files on the disk somewhere, not just 200GB

Comment: I have included hidden folders. The drive size dropped immediately after I'd copied only a few GB of files onto it.

Comment: @seanyboy what do you mean the "drive size" dropped?  Do you mean the free space on the drive increased dramatically, or the actual logical size of the disk decreased?

Answer (score 0):

Mind showing us a screen capture of the disk in disk management? It sounds strange to me...

Disk management is located in Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Computer managmeent

Comment: I have added screenshot as requested.

Comment: I think it looks legitimate to me. run chkdsk on the disk and see if there is any sector got loose. Sounds like some filesystem error if you can't find a file that occupies the space. You could perhaps format it and copy the file again in that case.

Comment: The drive is showing a huge number of bad sectors. I'll swap it out, see what happens.

Comment: So i guess that's the reason.. these days if you had bad sectors, it is probably best to just retire the drive. I am interested though, that 2TB drives are a relatively recent breed... Why are there so many bad sectors? problem with vibration/storage/usage?

Comment: Not sure why so many sectors should flag as bad. The disk format didn't report any errors.

Comment: I guess the best thing you could do is to do perhaps a scandisk or something similar. and check the SMART status of the drive. (e.g. Crystal Disk Info may be a good idea, free of charge)

Comment: @seanyboy the disk format will only report bad sectors if you do a *full* format, which essentially does the same thing as a quick formatting the drive, followed by running `chkdsk I: /R` (which scans the disk surface for bad sectors).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through these steps. Check drive space after each step.
1. Empty recycle bin. Recycle bin does occupy drive space.
2. Check drive for errors: `chkdsk i: /r /f`
3. Remove all but recent system restore snapshots for the drive.
4. Use disk cleanup to delete any unnecessary data if found.
5. Use a tool like SpaceSniffer  to visually check what is occupying the space.

Personally, I don't see how bad sectors could cause drive space being reported incorrectly.